# Finding Variance and Bias of a Function

Tags: self-study, variance, econometrics, bias, mse

First time using this website hopefully you guys could help me out.

I'm in an Econometrics class and I am having great difficulty with practice questions as I've been away for a year and a half from Econometrics.

[image: Econometric Questions]

Question a) I know that Bias=0 and variance = σ^2/n. What is the proof behind those answer that would suffice (how can I use MSE to get there).

Question b) I believe that Bias=0 and variance I don't know.

Question c) I don't know either.

PS. Is there any great free book that I could find online that you would recommend?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (c) is purely algebra: it doesn't matter that the $X_i$ are random variables; it's true in any algebraic system where these operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division by the natural number $n$) make sense and follow the usual rules of arithmetic. (a) and (b) are meaningless because they do not explain what parameters these statistics are attempting to estimate. You probably are supposed to assume (a) is intended to be an estimator of $\mu_1$ and (b) is intended to estimate $\mu_2$.

Comment: @Chris A little [search and research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) would be in order, in which case in relation to (a)  there's basic properties of [Expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) and [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)